# Determine whether series converge.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine if the series $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1} \ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right)$ converges.
$$\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1} \ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right) = \Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1} (\ln(n +(-1)^n) - \ln n ) \\ S_n = \ln(0) - \ln(1) + \ln(3) - \ln(2) + \ln(2) - \ln(3) + \ln(5) - \ln(4) + ... +\ln(n+(-1)^n) - \ln n $$

Looks like all terms cancel out except $ln(n + (-1)^n)$. So, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty \rightarrow$ series diverge, but I don't know what I can do with the term $ln(0)$ and whether I can manipulate with the series like that. So any advice would be welcome!

Comment: Your series is not well defined as you divide by 0 when $n=0$

Comment: @eminem Ok, it's incorrect, $n$ should be equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sum is from $n=2$ to $\infty$ then it converges to $0$. at $n=1$ it is undefined .

let us evaluate the sum from $n=2$ to $n=2m$ where $m$ is a large natural number. .

if it is from $n=2$ to $2m$ then rewrite it as :-

$\sum_{n=1}^{2m}( \ln(1+\frac{1}{2n})+\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}))$

Then all the terms cancel out except $\ln(\frac{2m+1}{2m})$.

If $m\to\infty$ then the sum tends to $\ln(1)=0$.

If we evaluate the sum for $n=2$ to $n=2m+1$.

Then all the terms cancel out and the summation is $0$.

Hence the sequence of partial sums $S_{n}=\sum_{r=2}^{n} ln(1+\frac{(-1)^{r}}{r})$ converges to $0$ , as it's sub-sequences both $S_{2m}$ and $S_{2m+1}$ converges to $0$.

So as the sequence of partial sums converge...we can say that the series converges to $0$.